# Visit meta links are incorrectly escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, character-escaping

<sub>I hope I have my terminology right with escaping and whatnot.</sub>

The quotes in the title are displaying as `&quot;` rather than ", if the image doesn't make it too obvious. The slug is also incorrectly escaped, with it pointing to `http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3996/do-you-quotsympathy-upvotequot`.

[image: bug plz fix]

Comment: This is in the process of being fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, a bug was introduced when I transitioned that ad from being backed by V1.1 of our API to the new hotness that is V2.0.  A fix has been deployed.

As an aside, it *also* revealed a few bugs in V2.0, so those were also fixed (though I doubt anyone noticed).